# Efficiently pairing temporally-related records using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, temporal, pairing

Consider a dataset where items can paired temporally.

For example, signing in and out of an area with a badge, one might record data such as this:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Time     ┃ BadgeId ┃ Direction ┃
┣══════════╪═════════╪═══════════┫
┃ 1001930  ┃ A       ┃ IN        ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1004901  ┃ B       ┃ IN        ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1005192  ┃ A       ┃ OUT       ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1012933  ┃ A       ┃ IN        ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1014495  ┃ B       ┃ OUT       ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1017891  ┃ A       ┃ OUT       ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

And then pair it temporally to obtain something like:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ BadgeId ┃ TimeIn   ┃ TimeOut  ┃
┣═════════╪══════════╪══════════┫
┃ A       ┃ 1001930  ┃ 1005192  ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ A       ┃ 1012933  ┃ 1017891  ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ B       ┃ 1004901  ┃ 1014495  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Given a dataset with hundreds of millions of such records, what would be the most efficient method of doing such temporal pairing? I'm interested in the theoretical best approach, and the most practically efficient approach using LINQ (or other set-based query language).

Comment: Order by BadgeID, Time, Direction. Then use MoreLINQ's `PairWise` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs Use `Where` to filter out pair entries where the BadgeID are different or where the first entry is not IN or the second entry is not OUT.

Comment: @mjwills You should post your comment as an answer. It's very likely the fastest method using `LINQ`.

Comment: @BrianvanRaak If you can write up a [mcve] with sample data, I'll put together an answer for you.

Comment: @mjwills Given that MoreLinq operates over IEnumerable, this isn't going to play that well with "hundreds of millions" of records. I imagine that an IQueryable linq query that can translate to SQL might be more appropriate.

Comment: Are your ins and outs guaranteed to be paired and not have strange overlaps? If not, how should this be dealt with?

Comment: @spender It might be - but that will be hard to write in SQL / LINQ. If you had a stored proc (with a CURSOR etc) you could do it more efficiently, yes. Is that an option Brian?

Comment: While it is very interesting to formulate a linq query that provides the result, pure linq is almost never the most efficient way (in terms of memory or performance) and is only more readable IMHO for relatively simple tasks. So why would you use linq here?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not the best theoretical approach to work with millions of records. However, this is working and can be used as a starting point for further improvements.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var StartingRecords = new List<Record>()
        {
            new Record(1001930, "A", "IN"),
            new Record(1004901, "B", "IN"),
            new Record(1005192, "A", "OUT"),
            new Record(1012933, "A", "IN"),
            new Record(1014495, "B", "OUT"),
            new Record(1017891, "A", "OUT"),
        };

        var records = StartingRecords.OrderBy(x => x.BadgeId).ThenBy(x => x.Time).ToList();

        var pairs = records.Skip(1).Zip(records, (second, first) => Tuple.Create(first, second)).
        Where(x => x.Item1.BadgeId == x.Item2.BadgeId &&
        x.Item1.Direction == "IN" && x.Item2.Direction == "OUT").
        Select(x => new Pair(x.Item1.BadgeId, x.Item1.Time, x.Item2.Time)).ToList();

        foreach (var pair in pairs)
            Console.WriteLine(pair.BadgeId + "\t" + pair.TimeIn + "\t" + pair.TimeOut);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Record
{
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string BadgeId { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    public Record(long time, string badgeId, string direction)
    {
        Time = time;
        BadgeId = badgeId;
        Direction = direction;
    }
}

class Pair
{
    public string BadgeId { get; set; }
    public long TimeIn { get; set; }
    public long TimeOut { get; set; }

    public Pair(string badgeId, long timeIn, long timeOut)
    {
        BadgeId = badgeId;
        TimeIn = timeIn;
        TimeOut = timeOut;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

`A       1001930 1005192
A       1012933 1017891
B       1004901 1014495`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient or performant this would be, but I think it can be translated by LINQ into SQL so if you are using a database, it may push more of the calculation to the server.

First, group the records by the badges:

```
var p1 = from p in punches
         group p by p.Badge into pg
         select new {
             Badge = pg.Key,
             Punches = pg.OrderBy(p => p.Time)
         };
```

Then, for each badge's group of records, go through all the "IN" records and match it with the "OUT" record if it exists:

```
var p2 = p1.SelectMany(pg => pg.Punches.Where(p => p.Dir == "IN")
                                       .Select(p => new {
                                            pg.Badge,
                                            TimeIn = p.Time,
                                            TimeOut = pg.Punches.Where(po => po.Dir == "OUT" && po.Time > p.Time)
                                                                .FirstOrDefault().Time
                                       }));
```

Finally, order the result:

```
var ans = p2.OrderBy(bio => bio.Badge).ThenBy(bio => bio.TimeIn);
```

Since LINQ to SQL propagates nulls automatically, I think this will handle a missing "OUT" punch for an "IN", but not orphan "OUT" punches.

Another possibility is to use the `Select` with two parameters to group the punch records in pairs, but that only works with LINQ to Objects so unless you are filtering the data before processing, the millions of records would all be pulled into memory.

For completeness, here is an attempt at it:

```
var p2 = p1.AsEnumerable()
           .SelectMany(pg => pg.Punches.Select((p, i) => (p, i))
                                       .GroupBy(pi => pi.i / 2, pi => pi.p)
                                       .Select(pp => new {
                                            pg.Badge,
                                            TimeIn = pp.Where(p => p.Dir == "IN").FirstOrDefault()?.Time,
                                            TimeOut = pp.Where(p => p.Dir == "OUT").FirstOrDefault()?.Time
                                       }));
```

None of this will work very well if your punches aren't well ordered, e.g. you are missing an initial "IN".